# bash script if / else case insensitive answers

Tags: bash

I have an if/else statement in a bash script that's asking if an EBS volume is going to be created from a snapshot id.

I'd like to create a line like: `if [ "$from_snapshot" -eq "Y|y" ]` but I don't think that will work.

Here's what I have:

```
  if [ "$from_snapshot" -eq "Y" ]
    then
      echo "Enter Snapshot ID: "
      read -r snapshot_id
   elif "$from_snapshot" -eq "y"
      echo "Enter Snapshot ID: "
      read -r snapshot_id
   else 
      echo "No Snapshot Required"
   fi
```

If there any way I can state that more succinctly?

Comment: Consider `case $from_snapshot in [Yy]) echo "yes code goes here";; *) echo "other code goes here";; esac` for a baseline-POSIX approach.

Comment: Alternatively, you could to change the case of your parameter: `[[ ${from_snapshot^} = Y ]]` or `[[ ${from_snapshot,} = y ]]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `-eq` operator in [`test` (aka `[`)](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-test) is used for *arithmetic* comparisons. That's certainly not what you want; you're trying to do a string comparison, which is the `=` operator. (Bash lets you type that as `==`, but `=` is what the standard requires.)

With bash, you are much better off using the [`[[` conditional command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-_005d_005d), which allows for "glob"-style pattern comparisons (and also regular expressions if you need that). So you could use

```
if [[ "$from_snapshot" = [Yy] ]]; then
```

Note: Do *not* put quotes around `[Yy]`. Quoting it will make it into a literal string instead of a pattern.

Answer (score 2):

In the more general case, you can use the `-o` option which performs a logical OR:

```
if [ \( "$from_snapshot" = "Y" \) -o \( "$from_snapshot" = "y" \) ]
then
  echo "Enter Snapshot ID: "
  read -r snapshot_id
else 
  echo "No Snapshot Required"
fi
```

Or you can use multiple tests with `||` between them:

```
if [ "$from_snapshot" = "Y" ] || [ "$from_snapshot" = "y" ]
then
  echo "Enter Snapshot ID: "
  read -r snapshot_id
else 
  echo "No Snapshot Required"
fi
```

Comment: Note the `OB` flags in [the POSIX `test` spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) -- passing more than four arguments to a single `test` command, or using `-o`, `-a` or parens, is obsolescent behavior (and an XSI extension, rather than baseline POSIX, even prior to that designation). The core issue is that it's ambiguous -- `test` can't tell if parens are intended to be literal or syntactic; is `[ '(' = ')' ]` supposed to be asking whether `=` is an empty string, with that test inside a group, or checking whether `(` and `)` are the same character?